# The right way to create an OnBeforeSave event in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm learning using Entity Framework Core and I just want to make my own `DbContext` have an event. I don't know how to describe it, so I show my code here:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext([NotNull] DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected MyDbContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

    public delegate void OnBeforeSaveDelegate(IEnumerable<EntityEntry> sender);
    public event OnBeforeSaveDelegate OnBeforeSave;

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries();
        OnBeforeSave?.Invoke(entries);
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Then in my handle code, I could use something like

```
public class MyHandle
{
    private MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext();

    public MyHandle()
    {
        dbContext.OnBeforeSave += AssignDateTime;
    }

    private void AssignDateTime(IEnumerable<EntityEntry> sender)
    {
        foreach (var entry in sender)
        {
            if (entry.Entity is IDatetimeStampable stampable) //Imagine this is an interface with have ModifiedDate and CreatedDate 
            {
                if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    stampable.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                    stampable.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
                else if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    stampable.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    public void AddStudent(Student input)
    {
        dbContext.Students.Add(input);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But when I call `dbContext.SaveChange()` my entities which are implemented from `IDatetimeStampable` still have default `DateTime` (01/01/0001 00:00:00).

Can someone point me what is wrong?

Edit: show more entity class and `IDatetimeStampable`

```
public interface IDatetimeStampable 
{
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

public class Student : IDatetimeStampable 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Implements
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Added into my question

Comment: I added method AddStudent in my `MyHandle` class. I using dependency injection, so, I can't show you how was `MyDbContext` created

Comment: Why you need an `event` to set create an update date? You can simply move `AssignDateTime` method to `DbContext` class without dealing with the event.

Comment: yeah, i could move AssignDateTime and call it easily but I want that assign is not by me. I mean, some developer will want assign datetime by DateTime.UtcNow instead of DateTime.Now.

Comment: I want create an `OnBeforeCreate`, and `AssignDateTime` is just a example of its usage

Comment: yes, break point is hit. But variable `entries` in `SaveChanges()` is unchanged. Seem what change in event just change in local scope, not affect to main thread

Comment: Will it work if you call `AssignDateTime` directly in `SaveChanges` and not via event?

Comment: yes, It worked if I call `AssignDateTime` directly in `SaveChanges`

Comment: Sorry but I have to active this question again